# From cylindrical velocity to cartesian

Tags: polar-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I am struggling with this. I need to convert this velocity in cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates:

$$
V(r, \theta, z) \: \mathrm{to} \: V(u,v,w)
$$

$$
 V_{r} = 10; \: V_{\theta}= 0; \: V_{z}=0;
$$

How can I find the $u,v,w$ components?

Edit:
Will it be?:

$$
u = V_{r} \cos(\theta) - V_{\theta} \sin(\theta) 
$$

$$
v = V_{r} \sin(\theta) + V_{\theta} \cos(\theta)
$$

$$
w = V_{z}
$$
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in terms of derivatives, $V_r=\frac{dr}{dt},$ $V_\theta=\frac{d\theta}{dt},$ and $V_z=\frac{dz}{dt}.$

Since $u=r\cos\theta,$ $v=r\sin\theta,$ and $w=z,$ then the Chain and Product rules get us $$V_u=\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}\cos\theta - r\sin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}=V_r\cos\theta-rV_\theta\sin\theta,$$ $$V_v=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}\sin\theta + r\cos\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}=V_r\sin\theta+rV_\theta\cos\theta,$$ and $$V_w=V_z.$$

Consequently, in general, we need to know more than just the cylindrical velocities, but also the cylindrical coordinates. In this case we only need to know $\theta,$ as substitution gets us $V_u=10\cos\theta,$ $V_v=10\sin\theta,$ and $V_w=0.$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The velocity in cylindrical coordinates is
$$\vec v=\dot r\hat e_r +r\dot\theta \hat e_\theta+\dot z\hat e_z$$
Now identify $\dot r=V_r,\dot\theta =V_\theta,\dot z=V_z$, substitute the basis vectors $\hat e_r,\hat e_\theta, \hat e_z$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Transform from cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$ to Cartesian coordinates $(u, v, w)$ is given by:

$$
\begin{aligned}
u &= r\cos(\theta) \\
v &= r\sin(\theta) \\
w &= z \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
V(u, v, w) &= V(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z) \Rightarrow \\
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
V_r &= V_u\cdot \cos(\theta) + V_v\cdot \sin(\theta) + V_w\cdot 0 \\
V_{\theta} &= V_u\cdot \left(-r\sin(\theta)\right) + V_v\cdot r\cos(\theta) + V_w\cdot 0 \\
V_z &= V_u\cdot 0 + V_v\cdot 0 + V_w\cdot 1
\end{aligned}
\right\} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{pmatrix}
V_r \\ V_{\theta} \\ V_z
\end{pmatrix} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
-r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
V_u \\ V_v \\ V_w
\end{pmatrix} \Leftrightarrow \\
\begin{pmatrix}
V_u \\ V_v \\ V_w
\end{pmatrix} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
-r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
V_r \\ V_{\theta} \\ V_z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

So, you have to find an inverse matrix of $\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
-r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  1
\end{pmatrix}$ and multiply it by
$\begin{pmatrix}
V_r \\ V_{\theta} \\ V_z
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
10 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Is this correct? The first matrix, 2nd line, shouldn't it be diving the $r$?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. This is a transform from $(V_u, V_v, V_w)$ to $(V_r, V_\theta, V_z)$. To get a transform from $(V_r, V_\theta, V_z)$ to $(V_u, V_v, V_w)$, one has to find an inverse of the matrix and use it.